# ERROR ZODB.Connection Couldn't load state for 0x130f

Tags: python, zodb, plone-3.x

```
2017-05-22T00:40:49 ERROR ZODB.Connection Couldn't load state for 0x130f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.8.3-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/                                                                                                                           ZODB/Connection.py", line 811, in setstate
    self._setstate(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.8.3-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/                                                                                                                           ZODB/Connection.py", line 852, in _setstate
    p, serial = self._storage.load(obj._p_oid, self._version)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.8.3-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/                                                                                                                           ZEO/ClientStorage.py", line 712, in load
    return self.loadEx(oid, version)[:2]
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.8.3-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/                                                                                                                           ZEO/ClientStorage.py", line 740, in loadEx
    self._cache.store(oid, ver, tid, None, data)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.8.3-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/                                                                                                                           ZEO/cache.py", line 136, in call
    return self.func(inst, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.8.3-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/                                                                                                                           ZEO/cache.py", line 557, in store
    nfreebytes = self._makeroom(size)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.8.3-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/                                                                                                                           ZEO/cache.py", line 370, in _makeroom
    size = int(status)
ValueError: invalid literal for int():
------
```

i just looked into the logs and found that ZODB is giving error. Does the issue related to blobstorage or something else?